# Parameterize and update the same excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, parameterized

I'm newbie to pytest, I'm using parameterize to iterate the testcases

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input',list(Utility.readExcel("Input.xlsx", "Sheet1")))
```

Now at the end I need to update the same `exce[Input.xlsx]` with some value for each iteration.
How can I do that? How can I know which row to update the value?

Comment: do you need to test each iterate separately or you need all list as one test ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here input data is a list of values needed for each test. So every iteration i need a fresh new list of data.